# PHP format number to omit trailing zeros

Tags: php

A while ago I wrote a fully working script to magically move the decimal sign, adapted to the number of zeros there are.

https://github.com/jenstornell/magic-number-format/blob/master/magic-number-format.php

I still wonder, is there a PHP function to cover this issue? I feel like my code is just too much:

```
<?php
function magic_number_format($number) {
    $pos = strpos($number, '.');
    $pos = ( ! $pos ) ? strpos($number, ',') : $pos;

    if( $pos ) {
        $count = strlen($number) - $pos - 1;
        $last = substr($number, -$count);
        $split = str_split($last);
        $split = array_reverse($split);

        $break = false;

        foreach( $split as $char ) {
            if( $char == 0 && $break == false ) {
                $count--;
            }

            if( $char != 0 ) {
                $break = true;
            }
        }

        $first = number_format( substr($number, 0, $pos ), 0, '', '.' );
        $last = substr($number, $pos + 1, $count);
        $result = $first . ',' . $last;

        $result = ( ! is_numeric( substr($result, -1) ) ) ? substr($result, 0, -1) : $result;

        return $result . "\n";
    }
    return number_format( $number, 0, '', '.' ) . "\n";
}

echo magic_number_format('25');
echo magic_number_format('123.32');
echo magic_number_format('12312.3233');
echo magic_number_format('12.0100000');
echo magic_number_format('1231,00');
echo magic_number_format('1231,10');
echo magic_number_format('1,1');
```

The code above will skip the unneeded zeros after the comma or dot sign.

Comment: what is expected output for each ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are reinventing the wheel. Also the code in answer linked as duplicate is not necessary neither the only approach nor the best approach (it also is not necessary fully related to your question). You can successfully stick using plain `printf()` with ordinary `%s` formatting for expected results. Test case:

```
$vals = [ 1, 1.000, 1.1, 1.230 ];
foreach ($vals as $val) {
    printf("%s\n", $val);
}
```

would produce desired:

```
1     
1                                                                                                                                                      
1.1                                                                                                                                                         
1.23
```

Replace `printf)` with `sprintf()` if you need to assing formatted value to a variable and you are good to go.

Comment: Yes, that's the best answer so far. A one-liner. In my case i switched from printf to sprintf and I also needed to force (float) to my value because else it will not work on strings. But great solution! Thanks!